# How to send parameters to Firebase Functions from FirebaseFunctions on Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am using a onRequest function in Firebase Functions to send an email with nodemailer.

Testing the function using a https:// request in my browser works perfectly fine if I pass in the parameters at the end in the format `?senderName=Bob`

In my function I use `req.query.senderName` to retrieve the variables.

When I use the Flutterfire cloud_functions dart plugin I cannot get my variables to pass to my function.
Below is my code:

```
  Future<void> sendEmail() async {
    FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;
    //TODO:remove when deployed
    //functions.useFunctionsEmulator(origin: 'http://localhost:5001');
    HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('sendEmail');
    try {
      final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable.call(
        {
          'senderName': contactName,
        },
      );
      print(result.data);
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
      print('Firebase Functions Exception');
      print(e.code);
      print(e.message);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Caught Exception');
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I've logged the value of 'req' in the firebase function and it returns the following lines (most lines removed for clarity)

```
query: {},
...
body: { data: { senderName: 'Bob' } },
...
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong for my variables to end up in 'body' and not 'query' or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not intended to mix onRequest type HTTP functions with the Firebase SDK that uses callable functions.  The SDK for callable functions is only meant to call onCall type functions, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).  Callable functions functions have a special [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference), and the SDK hides all of those details from you.

If you don't want to write an onCall function, and instead need to use onRequest, then you should not use the Firebase SDK to invoke it.  You should use a normal HTTP client for Flutter.

Comment: Thank you. I've been going over the materials for hours. All it took is someone to point out what's right in front of me 